# two criteria in Column 1 and add corresponding values in Column 3

Tags: excel, criteria, sumproduct

I want to add numbers in Column 3 that correspond to 2 or more criteria in Column 2, while referencing to Column 1

I tried using SUMPRODUCT in excel, but I am not able to make the formula concise

```
=sumproduct(--(A1:A5="fruit"),(--(B1:B5="mango"),C1:C5)+
sumproduct(--(A1:A5="fruit"),(--(B1:B5="pineapple"),C1:C5)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55653844/edit) to provide us with sample data and expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You have more `(` than `)`

But you do not need to do more than one SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="fruit")*((B1:B5="mango")+(B1:B5="pineapple")),C1:C5)
```

The `((B1:B5="mango")+(B1:B5="pineapple"))` is saying B1:B5 is either `mango` OR `pineapple`

But this can also be done with SUMIFS()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Fruit",B:B,{"mango","pineapple"}))
```

Comment: Thank you! My file is already big as it is. This is one big help :)